# Show Null Value from 2 comparable records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have example data table from attendance machine system like this:

```
ID    Name      In
1     John      2015-04-17 08:00:00
1     John      2015-04-17 16:30:00
1     John      2015-04-20 10:01:00
1     John      2015-04-21 10:00:00
1     John      2015-04-21 19:00:00
```

Here my query:

```
SELECT a.id AS ID, a.nama AS `Name`, DATE_FORMAT(a.att, '%d-%b-%y') AS `Date`, 
DATE_FORMAT(a.att, '%T') as `IN`, DATE_FORMAT(b.att, '%T') AS `OUT`
FROM attendance a 
INNER JOIN attendance b
on date(a.att) = date(b.att) AND a.id = b.id
WHERE b.att > a.att
```

With above query I can split the In (column) time into 2 column become In and out like this:

```
Id  Name   Date        In         Out 
1   John   17-Apr-15   08:00:00   16:30:00
1   John   21-Apr-15   10:00:00   19:00:00
```

The problem is if user John forget to use finger print where he out, for example on date 20 April, the data is not display. So, I want to my output become like this:

```
Id  Name   Date        In         Out 
1   John   17-Apr-15   08:00:00   16:30:00
1   John   20-Apr-15   10:01:00   NULL
1   John   21-Apr-15   10:00:00   19:00:00
```

Comment: but what happens if John forgets to print IN instead of forgetting to print OUT?

Comment: No problem, I only want to check where user who forget present. Maybe I can analyze using PHP to check if a user forgot In or Out. Thank you for reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN. Or you can use this query instead:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  Name,
  DATE(att) AS `Date`,
  DATE_FORMAT(MIN(att), '%T') AS `In`,
  CASE WHEN MAX(att)<>MIN(att) THEN DATE_FORMAT(MAX(att), '%T') END AS `Out`
FROM
  attendance 
GROUP BY
  Id, Name, DATE(att)
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7f88/4).